# Play and Stop Flash from JQuery?

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript

Is there any way to play, stop or gotoAndPlay(anyframe) from JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Here is generic javascript code to gotoAndPlay:

```
var movie = window.document.movie;
movie.GotoFrame(24);
movie.Play();
```

[Details here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html)

Answer (score 0):

jquery doesn't matter. You need to call flash with the AS3 ExternalInterface class. Jquery might assign a listener, but the call itself is just vanilla javascript. Here's a good [tutorial](http://meshfields.de/externalinterface-call-as3-javascript/)